# How to change data type result of np.dot from float64 to uint8?

Tags: numpy, types

does anybody know how to change the type of the result "grayscale_image" to np.uint8? After applying "np.dot" it changes to type float 64:

```
LenaRGB = np.array(Image.open('Lena.png'), dtype=np.uint8)
rgb_weights = [0.2989, 0.5870, 0.1140]
grayscale_image = np.dot(LenaRGB[...,:3], rgb_weights)
```

Comment: Use the standard `numpy` `astype` method?  `np.dot` uses fast compiled code where possible, which would use standard `c` float or int types.

Comment: Yeah it worked, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you:

```
grayscale_image.astype(np.uint8)
```

Here is the documentation:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html